# VueJS accessing variable at window.frameElement from main.js returns null

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Question has been removed - ...

Comment: When do you get frameElement=null?  In the mounted() function shown here?   (I'm not really clear whether you're running Vue in the parent window trying to access data in the iframe, or the other way around.)

Comment: Commands entered into the console run in the context of the main window, so frameElement is going to be null there because it's not in an iframe.  From there, `window.frames[0]` would give you the iframed document (assuming it's the first or only one in the parent); `window.frames[0].frameElement` would circle back to the parent window's `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: At this point I think you may want to rewrite the question to show the actual object you're trying to access and how you're trying to access it -- the code sample you've provided doesn't appear to have anything to do with what you're asking as far as I can tell.  (Where is the attempt to access `creativeAPI` coming from?  Where was `creativeAPI` set?)

Comment: @DanielBeck Ah yes, realized it didnt make much sense anymore. Should read better now

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I think if you use `export {channel, dom, ...} = window.creativeAPI` you'll be in better shape; from inside the frame you'd access it as `window.creativeAPI`, or from the parent as `window.frames[0].window.creativeAPI`.  Right now you're attempting to attach `creativeAPI` to the iframe tag in the parent window; I'm not sure that would work (and seems unnecessarily rickety even if it did)...

Comment: @DanielBeck Tried that but just get Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined. I do think window.frameElement.creativeAPI is where it is as the engagement log in the console image[updated] above proves that the creativeAPI was reached but after that the window object gets reset somehow

Comment: But `window.frameElement` isn't the window object, it's the parent window's `<iframe>` tag.  I don't see how that can work at all, given that the iframe doesn't exist at compile time.  (Possibly that's why it's being overwritten?  Note that the your `console.log(window.frameElement)` doesn't output anything.)

Comment: @DanielBeck. Thanks for all your help so far, much appreciated! Please see the new code above and console logs to match, I have added a description at the top of each log which will hopefully make things clearer.